# Fading all but single instance of a button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a menu with 4 buttons. If the user taps on one, I highlight it to show that it is selected. When the user places the item corresponding to the button in the game scene, the button fades back out.

The problem I am having is that when I have a button selected and then select another button, both buttons are highlighting. The behavior I am trying to achieve is the first button fades when the second button is pressed.

I have tried setting the selectedButton to null, which calls the FadeAll() method from Update(), but both the first and second button clicked remain highlighted. When I click on the game scene, the GameObject corresponding to the latest button press is placed, and all buttons are faded.

Here is my class that controls button fading:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Button : MonoBehaviour {

    public static GameObject selectedButton;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject thisButton;
    private SpriteRenderer sprite;
    private Color originalColor;
    private Button[] buttons;
    private StarDisplay starDisplay;

    void Start () {
        starDisplay = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<StarDisplay>();
        buttons = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<Button>();
        sprite = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        originalColor = sprite.color;
        FadeAll();
    }

    void Update () {
        if (!selectedButton){
            FadeAll();
        }
    }

    private void FadeAll(){
        foreach (Button button in buttons){
            Color fade = sprite.color;
            fade.a = 0.5f;
            sprite.color = fade;
        }
    }

    void OnMouseDown(){
        //TODO error, if select one then select another, both highlight
        selectedButton = null;
        if (thisButton.GetComponent<Defender>().StarCost <= starDisplay.StarCount){
            selectedButton = thisButton;
            sprite.color = originalColor;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the relevant code from the other class that fades all buttons when one object is dropped into the game scene.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DefenderSpawner : MonoBehaviour {

    private Vector2 targetLocation;
    private GameObject parent;
    private StarDisplay starDisplay;
    private int defenderCost;
    void Start () {
        starDisplay = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<StarDisplay>();
        parent = GameObject.Find("Defenders");
        if (!parent){
            parent = new GameObject("Defenders");
        }
    }

    void OnMouseDown(){
        targetLocation = CalculateWorldPointOfMouseClick(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Button.selectedButton){
            defenderCost = Button.selectedButton.GetComponent<Defender>().StarCost;
            if (starDisplay.UseStars(defenderCost)){
                GameObject defender = Instantiate(Button.selectedButton, targetLocation, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                defender.transform.parent = parent.transform;
                Button.selectedButton = null;
            } else {
                print("Cannot afford defender");
            }
        }
    }
```

In the second class, all buttons fade when the selected Button == null. But in the first class this is not happening when I set selectedButton = null in OnMouseDown(). Any help finding out what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why dont you create an animation controller and make animations like fade-in and fade-out. Then just use Unity's internal event system connected with interfaces to handle mouse hover?

Comment: Maybe step back a bit. The built in buttons are already coded to fade in & out as other object are selected, it might be you don't need a lot of your code. Perhaps try an empty scene with none of your own code first and observe the behaviour of the built in buttons.